# Separable Differential Equations with log in the question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

the question is $y \log y-t(\dfrac{dy}{dt}) = 0$

I have separated the question to $4\dfrac{1}{t} dt = \dfrac{1}{y\log y} dy.$

Integrating would give me $log(t) = \log(y\log y) + c$.

How do I simplify the $\log$ to gain the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: $4\frac{dt}{t}$? Why $4$?

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\log(t) = \log(y \log(y)) + c$$
The constant can be written as $c=-\log(k)$, in which case, you get
$$\log(t) = \log(y \log(y)) - \log(k) \implies y \log(y) = kt \implies y^y = e^{kt}$$